# create table in ms-access using cfm file

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

i created a table in msaccess manually with following details
table name - "options"
optionid AUTONUMBER
productid NUMBER
optionname TEXT
sortid NUMBER
optionprice NUMBER

Now i want my cfm file to run the following query so that table get created but iam getting database error

```
CREATE TABLE options
(
    optionid INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT,
    productid INTEGER,
    optionname VARCHAR(255),
    sortid INTEGER,
    optionprice INTEGER
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try following the same rules as when you create the table manually:

```
CREATE TABLE options
(
    optionid NUMBER AUTONUMBER,
    productid NUMBER,
    optionname TEXT,
    sortid NUMBER,
    optionprice NUMBER 
);
```

Comment: yes i used the above query also given by you from my cfm file but i am still getting database error.

Comment: ok i got it when iam using following syntax its working properly   CREATE TABLE options
(
    optionid AUTOINCREMENT,
    productid NUMBER,
    optionname TEXT,
    sortid NUMBER,
    optionprice NUMBER 
);

Comment: @Ritu - Strictly personal perference, but I think your original is more intuitive. Just use the AUTONUMBER and TEXT types as duncan showed.  ie `ie CREATE TABLE Options (
optionid AUTOINCREMENT,
    productid INTEGER,
    optionname TEXT(255),
    sortid INTEGER,
    optionprice INTEGER

)`